# What is solution for the following integral function

Tags: definite-integrals

The following integral is taken from exercise 7.1 of james stewart calculus 7th edition early transcendentals

$$\int_0 ^te^s\sin(t-s)~ds$$

I tried integration by parts and got the answer as follows $-\frac{1}{2}[e^t+\cos(t)+\sin(t)]$. Please verify the answer and  if it is wrong please mention the correct procedure

Regards
Joe Joseph

Comment: Can you please check if what was edit is what you want to integerate

Comment: You could do an indefinite integral and then test it by doing the derivative and see if you obtain the original function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sign error in your solution: $$-1/2\left[-e^t+cos(t)+sin(t)\right].$$

For future reference, it might be worth your while to check out a symbolic algebra package to check your answers. I would recommend starting with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).